# Constructing a sql query joining several tables and advance grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **Order** table

```
  id   | order_status_id  | order_type_id  |   date
  -----------------------------------------------------
  41   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-21
  42   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-21
  43   |        12        |       2        | 2015-06-21
  44   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-22
  45   |        12        |       2        | 2015-06-22
  46   |        03        |       1        | 2015-06-22
  47   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-23
  48   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-24
  49   |        12        |       2        | 2015-06-24
  50   |        12        |       1        | 2015-06-25
```

I have a **Order_Status** table

```
  id  | order_status  | order_status_name 
  ----------------------------------------
   1  |       01      |       Draft    
   2  |       02      |     Accepted   
   3  |       03      |     Rejected    
   4  |       04      |     Processing
   -----------------------------------
   -----------------------------------
   -----------------------------------

   12 |       12      |     Completed
```

I have a **Order_Type** table

```
  id  | order_type_name 
  ---------------------
  1   | Pickup    
  2   | Delivery
```

**My Prob :** I need to construct a sql query for this scenario.

```
       Date    | No_of_pickup_orders | No_of_delivery_orders
  ----------------------------------------------------------
    2015-06-21 |          02         |         01    
    2015-06-22 |          01         |         01    
    2015-06-23 |          01         |         00  
    2015-06-24 |          01         |         01      
    ------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------
```

**Conditions :** This report should not have the records which has order_status_id = 03

Is this possible in sql with single query????

**What I Did So far.....**

```
   SELECT (date AS DATE) as 'Day', count(order_type_id)
   FROM order
   WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()-1)+6 DAY
   AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()-1)-1 DAY
   AND order_status_id != 3
   group by created_at;
```

**Explanation :** My database structure is much bigger than what i mentioned here. This is a simplified version. What I'm trying to do is to get the last week data from the order. That is why I used this "WHERE" clause and "AND" clause

Comment: Folks do not forget to link your SQLFiddle it helps a lot :)

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried?  Everyone is happy to help but it is best if you make some attempt yourself to answer the question.  Step 1 is: get a list of all the orders with the statuses you want to include (e.g. not the Rejected ones), their order_id, the date and whether it is pickup or collection.  Then you can work out how to start adding up those totals

Comment: SQLFiddle if it can help : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sum()` functions the condition `order_type_id=whatever` returns either 1 (true) or 0 (false). Instead of counting summing those return values up will give the result you want.

```
   SELECT date as 'Day', sum(order_type_id=1), sum(order_type_id=2)
   FROM `order`
   WHERE true
   -- created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()-1)+6 DAY
   -- AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()-1)-1 DAY
   AND order_status_id != 3
   group by date;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53779/11/0)

Comment: Any idea how to add missing date using this query??? Eg;- if i dont have records for a particular date, return zero, with the date

Comment: You can't select what isn't there. Create a (temporary if you like) table with dates, that you can left join on the range between your min and max date.